# I have a problem with my Visual Studio Code doing some weird stuff

Tags: python, module

So i have been coding for few days now learning python and doing some stuff and today i made my first successful program that worked as i intented it to work. But a bit after that i hit a roadblock with my code starting to give me problems. Not from where you would expect them, but every single one was from imports. I havent changed anything. Played war thunder with couple friends for couple hours and then saw this problem. I have done reinstalled my pip stuff and restarted pc with no avail. I am kind of lost right now. If someone has some information of this phenomenom would be highly apprecciated.

Sorry for not perfect english i hope you make some sense of this nonsense :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgQQ9.png)

I have tried reinstalling modules with pip uninstall pytube and same with pillow and then pip install.

Comment: Did you select a different python interpreter inside VS Code?

Comment: Please edit the question and add some information: the output of this command `pip show pytube`, and also the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Apparently that was the problem. I have 2 different versions of python installed. One i got from python's website and other one i got from microsoft store. And looks like its the microsoft store one that had switched from my global Python 3.10.6 to Recommended Python 3.12.1 Thanks actually that was it :D

Answer (score 0):

Select a python interpreter (click on the yellow button in the bottom right corner in VScode)
[image: base screenshot + red arrow indicating the button in the bottom right corner]

if python is on your system, you should see something like that :
[image: a pop-up with different python interpreters]

Then you should select the recommended option.

If you have several options, note that installs made using pip are not shared between each python version.

If you don't see any options here, you might want to add python to the path or re-install python using the microsoft store.